# C++ - More organized and efficient function prototyping

Tags: c++, prototyping, function-prototypes

Is there a more organized way to use function prototyping or something similar and more efficient? I've had a few problems with function prototyping getting unorganized and filling most of my files with externs and voids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that under `function prototyping` you are asking how to organize  all function signatures so that other compilation modules can reuse them.

- Obvious: put prototype into header files
- Use headers generators ([Makeheaders](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/mkhdr/),  [GCC AutoInclude](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2011-01/msg00150.html)) - so that you do not have to write these yourself.

Comment: I was mainly wanting to know if there was a more efficient or standard way to use global functions.

Comment: Why both of your links are pointing to the same place? :)